# missing app version when submitting app to app store

Tags: ios, app-store, archive

i am trying to submit my app to the app store 
i have completed all the steps and i reached the itunes connect page where it asks to upload the build. but when i try and archive the app. In the organiser the validate, upload to app store, export options all are disabled and when i try and download the dsym files(the only working link) it says missing app version.For your reference i have uploaded the screenshots.[image: screenshot of organiser showing the disabled buttons]

[image: screenshot of build settings of the target[![][2]]][3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wWDul.png)

Answer (score 1):

Notice on the right hand side that it says "Distribution requires enrollment in the apple developer program".

You are building / archiving without a proper provisioning profile and certs that are enrolled in the apple developer program.

Click your project in the file navigator to the left. Then click on the General tab and select your team license from the Team dropdown.

Then click the build settings tab and do a search for `Code Signing` and set your Release option to your certificate and the Provisioning Profile to your provisioning profile.

Comment: i have a paid developer id its my first app so could you tell me where can i get the required profiles